# How do I read a file without crashing AutoCAD?

Tags: c#, autocad

I have a text file that is stored on network location. This file is used in the AutoCAD for some purpose. In some instances, there we have a issue where two users simultaneously request this file and one user gets the access while for the second user AutoCAD crashes because file is being used by another user. To prevent that we started copying the files to Appdata folder and did this.

```
  internal string GetProjectLocation()
  {
    string strNetworkPath= "XXXX.com\Workdirs\Private\Projects.txt";
    return GetValidPath(strNetworkPath);
  }

private string GetValidPath(string strFullPath)
{
    string strLocalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + @"\Acad-Data\";
    string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFullPath);
    if (!FileInUse(strFullPath))
    {
        return strFullPath;     
    }

    string strLocalFilePath= strLocalPath + strFileName;
    if (File.Exists(strLocalFilePath))
        return strLocalFilePath;

    return strFullPath;
}

internal bool FileInUse(string sFile)
{
    bool rtnValue = false;

    try
    {
        using (System.IO.FileStream f = new System.IO.FileStream(sFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.None))
        {
            rtnValue = false;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        rtnValue = true;
    }
    return rtnValue;
}`
```

But even after doing this the program still crashes with the same error that says

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file "\XXXX.com\Workdirs\Private\Projects.txt" because it is being used by another process.

Please note that I have verified that the file exists in Appdata folder. What should I do to prevent AutoCAD crash while making this work.

Comment: Try reading the stream, not just opening it.

Comment: make a new copy in app data delete after use/few huours

Comment: I am making copy of the file in appdata everytime AutoCAD is opened.

Comment: I also tried reading the stream before it didn't help so I removed that portion when I was pasting code here

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why your application keeps crashing while reading the TXT file from the copy you have in your appdata folder. You do not show that piece of code.

I do know of a way to copy a locked file. If you could change that method with the one provided below, the problem should be resolved.

Try using this extension method to get a copy of the locked file first. It should provide u with a workable file. It would also remove the need to keep a copie of the file at the start of the application.

Although I do not recommend working on files like this if there is any writing from the host/client applications to the source file. Will definitely lead to problems. This is why they invented databases ;) .

#### Usage example

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Locked autoCAD File
            var lockedFile = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\test.dwg";

            // Lets copy this locked file and read the contents
            var unlockedCopy = new 
            FileInfo(lockedFile).GetCopy(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\test-copy.dwg");

            // Open file with default app to show we can read the info.
            Process.Start(unlockedCopy);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

#### Extension method

```
internal static class LockedFiles
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Makes a copy of a file that was locked for usage in an other host application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> String with path to the file. </returns>
    public static string CopyLocked(this FileInfo sourceFile, string copyTartget = null)
    {
        if (sourceFile is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sourceFile));
        if (!sourceFile.Exists)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Parameter {nameof(sourceFile)}: File should already exist!");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(copyTartget))
            copyTartget = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var inputFile = new FileStream(sourceFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, 
        FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (var outputFile = new FileStream(copyTartget, FileMode.Create))
            inputFile.CopyTo(outputFile, 0x10000);

        return copyTartget;
    }
}
```